# Class attribute error while creating python object

Tags: python, class, pygame, attributes

I am writing a small game. I want to create two objects from the same class and combine them into a group. But when creating the second object, an error occurs "AttributeError: 'Enemy' object has no attribute 'get_rect'"

Here is the code related to the problem

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = enemy
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (200, 200)
        self.speedx = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.speedy = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.collis = 0
        self.enemy_health = 5
        self.enemy_rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.rect.x + 35, self.rect.y + 20), (35, 15))
        self.skin = 0
        self.skin_index = 0
        self.skins = [enemy, enemy_1, enemy_2]
        self.left_skins = [pygame.transform.flip(self.skins[0], True, False),
                           pygame.transform.flip(self.skins[1], True, False),
                           pygame.transform.flip(self.skins[2], True, False)]
        self.move_enemy = 1

    def update(self, collis):

        self.enemy_rect = pygame.rect.Rect((self.rect.x + 35, self.rect.y + 20), (35, 15))
        if self.move_enemy == 1:
            if self.collis < 1:
                self.speedx = random.randint(1, 2)
                self.speedy = random.randint(1, 2)
                if player.player_x_pos > self.rect.x:
                    self.rect.x += self.speedx
                    self.skin += 1
                    if self.skin % 10 == 0:
                        self.skin_index += 1
                        if self.skin_index > 2:
                            self.skin_index = 0
                    self.image = self.skins[self.skin_index]

                if player.player_y_pos + 50 > self.rect.y:
                    self.rect.y += self.speedy
                    self.skin += 1
                    if self.skin % 10 == 0:
                        self.skin_index += 1
                        if self.skin_index > 2:
                            self.skin_index = 0
                    self.image = self.skins[self.skin_index]

                if player.player_x_pos < self.rect.x:
                    self.rect.x -= self.speedx
                    self.skin += 1
                    if self.skin % 10 == 0:
                        self.skin_index += 1
                        if self.skin_index > 2:
                            self.skin_index = 0
                    self.image = self.left_skins[self.skin_index]

                if player.player_y_pos + 50 < self.rect.y:
                    self.rect.y -= self.speedy
                    self.skin += 1
                    if self.skin % 10 == 0:
                        self.skin_index += 1
                        if self.skin_index > 2:
                            self.skin_index = 0
                    if player.player_x_pos < self.rect.x:
                        self.image = self.left_skins[self.skin_index]
                    else:
                        self.image = self.skins[self.skin_index]

            else:
                self.collis = 0
            # if self.enemy_health <= 0:
            #     del enemy
            print('Health:', self.enemy_health)
        if self.move_enemy == 2:
            if self.rect.y <= 550:
                self.rect.y += 2
            else:
                self.rect.y -= 2

enemy = Enemy()
enemy2 = Enemy()
enemy2.rect.center = (100, 100)
scene_1_sprites.add(enemy2)
scene_1_sprites.add(enemy)
```

But the class has the necessary attribute

I tried to create the second object like this:
enemy2 = enemy

But in the end there was only one object

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "But the class has the necessary attribute" In your own words, why do you think this is? Where do you think that value is coming from? Where is the code where you make it have that attribute?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course an `Enemy` does not have a `get_rect` method. The error message is very clear. The problem here is:

> ```py
> class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
>    def __init__(self):
>        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
>        self.image = enemy                      #<---
>        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
> ```

This is because the `enemy` is itself an `Enemy` object:

> ```py
> enemy = Enemy()
> ```

Most likely you have used the same name (`enemy`) for the object instance of the `pygame.Surface` (image) and the object instance of the `Enemy`. You cannot use the same name for 2 different things (variables). So creating the first `enemy"` will work, but all subsequent ones will fail.

Change the name of the image:

<s>`enemy = pygame.image.load(....)`</s>

```py
enemy_image = pygame.image.load(....)
```

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = enemy_image              #<---
```